# RailsAdmin set different default devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-admin

I have two different devise user models, User and AdminUser, this has originally come from an ActiveAdmin setup.

I have now switched to RailsAdmin and I want the default user model to be the AdminUser and to prevent the User model from having access to the administration pages. Currently logging in under either model will allow access.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :admin_users
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin' 
devise_for :users
```

Comment: I just switched back to using ActiveAdmin :), I can't remember now why I was messing with RailsAdmin